# Console does not show "Caused by:" notes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

When I get an error in Android Studio debugger, I see only a part of errors (I think) because the log seems to be truncated and the "Caused by:.." section is always missing.
I attach here below an example of the error I got:

[Debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si06S.jpg)

As you can see the last "at android.app.ActivityThre" is truncated and I never see the "Caused by" error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: In the top-right drop down menu, select "No Filters" and check if you can see the whole stack trace.

Comment: The message just above the stacktrace says "shutting the JVM" and its timestamp is before the stacktrace's, so I'm worried it just got interrupted while it was working. The error message is quite clear though, it should be enough for this specific case.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I tried your method but without success. Now I have more messages but the "Caused by" is not shown. I am doing an online course and the teacher (same code) have a debug log different. The code is a simple code that is made by setting a button == null and then setting the method setOnClickListener. He got also the part of log that states "Caused by.." and I haven't.